# what can I do if a program can be run by python console while can not be run by ipython console?

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

It seems that the spyder has removed python console, but I got a program can only be run by python console, what can I do? or is there any thing I am wrong?

I got some codes from [github](https://github.com/wangshub/wechat_jump_game), and it needs ADB driver for Android, after I installed ADB, I can run the program in cmd using `python wechat_jump_auto.py`, but cannot run in spyder with ipython.

Comment: Did you install it in your spyder environment? Note, you can install ipython in your standard environment too.

Comment: I don't know how to install the python console in spyder...

Answer (score 1):

In Spyder3 installed in Windows OS, we can add the path to adb using Tools --> Current user environment variables....
Here, we can add the path to adb.exe file by appending it to the path variable. Then, we need to restart Spyder3. Then you will be able to directly run your script with access to adb.exe from Spyder3 IPython console or simply by clicking Run button.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem as you recently.

In fact, it seems that program using ADB tools just cannot run in Spyder even by python console (my Spyder IDE is equipped with both Ipython console and Python console).

One practical way to solve this problem is to run your code in cmd.

Open your cmd window and do something like this:

```
python "xxx(path)\xxxx.py(file name)"
```

In my case, it looks like this:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMfw7.png)

Hit Enter, and hopefully your code will run successfully.

If it still cannot run, maybe you haven't set your environment variables correctly.

Hope this can solve your problem. Good luck :)